# CakePHP 2.0 - Pagination for an image gallery (with different item limits)

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, gallery, cakephp-2.0

I want to build a small image gallery with CakePHP. Therefore I created an index view which displays a 3x3 table with image thumbnails. For pagination and sorting I added the following code:

ImagesController.php:

```
var $paginate = array(
            'limit' => 9,
            'order' => array('Image.id' => 'desc')
            );     

public function index() {  
  $data = $this->paginate('Image');
  $this->set('images', $data);
}
```

index.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id', 'Id'); ?> | 
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name', 'Title'); ?>
...
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev(' << Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('first' => 2, 'last' => 2)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next >> ', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
```

This works great. Now, when you click on a thumbnail a single image will be displayed using a view named 'view' (e.g. localhost/gallery/images/view/1). Like the index view, this view should have a pagination too, where the image with the id of 1 is currently selected and where you can navigate to the n previous and next images relative to the currently selected one. Moreover the images should be sorted by the same criteria as the pictures on the index view (e.g. by name). Is there an elegant way to solve this problem with CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this by passing the page number from the original pagination to the detail view.

If you were looking at Image ID `1` on page `2`, your URL would look something like:

```
/gallery/images/view/1/2
```

That is:

```
/gallery/images/view/:id/:page
```

From this information, you can query the same paginated data from the index action on the specified page, and provide back and next navigation options from that data.